# How to specify /D in FOR command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The Windows command line interpreter features a FOR command, which is able to parse the output of a given command and execute the loop for each line of the output, e.g.:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR .') DO echo %i # Outputs each file name
```

The command (`DIR .`)  is executed in a child command line via `cmd /C <command> <command-arguments>`, however, the `/D` parameter is not specified ... this leads to weird behavior if the user has a AutoRun command with output (e.g. echo, or cls).

Is there a way to force FOR to execute the command via `cmd /C /D <command> <command-arguments>`?

Comment: A very simple work-around is to use an intermediate file instead of a command: `DIR . > DIR.txt` &  `FOR /F %%i IN (DIR.txt) DO echo %%i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple solution for your problem is use a *file* in the `for /F` command instead of a *command*. This way, we just emulate the internal operation of `for /F` over a command, but executing each step explicitly: **1.** Execute the command and store its output in a temporary text file. **2.** Process all lines in the temporary file. **3.** Delete the file.

```
DIR . > TempFile.txt
FOR /F %%i IN (TempFile.txt) DO echo %%i
DEL TempFile.txt
```

Comment: Excellent idea, and simple to implement.

Answer (score 6):

You have run across one of the many design flaws of cmd.exe, and this one has bothered me for quite some time. I'm pretty sure there is no way to suppress AutoRun when FOR /F executes a command.

What makes this especially irritating is that pipes also use CMD /C (one for each side of the pipe), but the designers of the pipe were smart enough to incorporate both the /D and /S options. It is really a shame the designers of FOR /F couldn't have done the same.

<strike>I believe your only recourse</strike> One option is to be defensive within your AutoRun command definition. I suggest putting all the AutoRun commands within a batch script that has something like the following at the top:

```
@echo off
if defined AutoRunComplete exit /b
set AutoRunComplete=1
REM Put your AutoRun commands below...
```

But if you cannot control the AutoRun commands, then <strike>I think you are out of luck.</strike> [Aacini's idea of using a temporary file to get around the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015509/1012053) is an effective and simple solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - unfortunately, I cannot control the AutoRun file, the issue happened at a customer site and we wanted to make sure that we cannot run into the same situation in the future again. Do you know by chance of any MS Connect issue discussing the issue?

Comment: @D.R. - The best I could find is at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433

Answer (score 2):

When you have many FOR /F blocks for parsing program output, then it could be useful to add a cmd.exe wrapper.

This wrapper can be *installed* with

```
set "comspec=C:\somewhere\cmdWrapper.exe"
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR .') DO echo %%i
```

The wrapper itself has to start the original cmd.exe with `/D /C`.

But the behaviour of the [comspec variable](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7006) itself is a bit strange.

Comment: Another interesting idea. I suppose you could implement the wrapper with CSCRIPT. But the "strange" behavior where cmd FOR /F caches the COMSPEC value makes the technique unreliable. I don't see how you can control whether your script is the first one run that uses FOR /F.

Comment: I tried CSRIPT already, but it fails as it doesn't accept the `/C` option. Currently I'm playing with `.hta` files for mshta, but I can't get it working, as it seems, that only .exe are valid for `comspec` but not file associations